# Samba: Replace only illegal characters, instead of using a completely gibberish file name?

Tags: linux, samba

I understand that Linux and Windows have different set of illegal characters, but it seems when a file name contains even a single special character like `:` on a Samba shared directory (Linux server), the whole file name becomes gibberish.

For example, "a:b" becomes "A4WTMA~A". That is not so helpful to know what the file is... Can I make the name more predictable? Like,

- Replace only special characters to "_".
- If that name already exists, add a number at the end.

So, if

- a:b
- a_b
- a?b

exist on Linux it would be shown on Windows as

- a_b1
- a_b
- a_b2

on Windows, or something like that instead of,

- A4WTMA~A
- a_b
- A6ARMU~L

as they currently are shown?

Comment: What charset is being used in the Samba server config for the following two values: `display charset` / `dos charset` _(`display charset` may be depreciated, as I'm not seeing it on the man page)_ and `unix charset`.  It may be more efficient to fix the issue, rather than the symptom (see [smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) man page)

Comment: See the answers to an earlier duplicate question: https://superuser.com/questions/458995/files-folders-get-weird-names-and-become-inaccessible-on-samba-share